# Inserting deleted data back into dataset using temp table. Qlikview

Tags: database, qlikview

I am having trouble working out the logic to this little scenario.  Basically I have a data set and it is stored on weeks of the year and  each week the previous weeks data is deleted from the data set.  What I need to do is copy the previous weeks data before its removed from the data set and then add it back after it's removed.  So for example if today is week 33, I need to save this and then next week add it back in.  Then next week I need to take week 34 and save that to add in during week 35.  A picture explains better than a thousand words so here it is.

[image]

As you can see I need the minimum week from the data set before I add the previous weeks data.  The real issue that I'm finding is that the dataset can be rerun more than once each week so I would need to keep the temp data set until the next week while extracting the Minimum weeks data set.

It's more logic I'm after here...Hope it makes sense and thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QVD's are the way forward! Although maybe not as another (very good) answer states.

```
--Load of data from system
Test:    
Load *
, today() as RunDate
From SourceData

--Load of data from QVD
Test:
Load *
From Test.QVD

--Store current load into QVD
Store Test into Test.QVD
```

This way you only have one QVD of data that continually expands.

**Some warnings**

- You will need to bear in mind that report runs multiple times a week so you will need to cater for duplication in the data load.
- QVD loads aren't encrypted, so put your data somewhere safe
- when loading from a QVD and then overwriting it, if something goes wrong (the load fails) you will need to recover your QVD so make sure your backup solution is up to the task.

I also added the RunDate field so that it is easier for you to take apart when reviewing as this gives you the same split as storing in separate QVD's would.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you should store the data out into weekly QVD files as part of an Extract process and then load the resulting files in.

The logic would be something like the below...

First run (week 34 for week 33 data):

- Get data for previous week
- Store into file correctly dated - e.g. 2016-33 for week 33 of 2016
- Drop this table
- Load all QVDs (in this case just 1)

Next week run (week 35 for week 33 & 34 data):

- Get data for previous week
- Store into file correctly dated - e.g. 2016-34 for week 34 of 2016
- Drop this table
- Load all QVDs (in this case 2)

Repeat run next week (week 35 for week 33 & 34 again data):

- Get data for previous week
- Store into file correctly dated - e.g. 2016-34 for week 34 of 2016 (this time overwrite it)
- Drop this table
- Load all QVDs (in this case 2)

Sensible file naming solve the problem, but if you really actually need to inspect the data to check the week number, you would need to first load all existing QVDs, query the minimum week number and take it from there probably.

Comment: Appreciate the response.  The problem with the solution is that it will eventually accumulate to a mountain of QVDs which is not ideal.  Also what I forgot to mention is that once week 35 has been run and week 34 is added, the week 33 data is no longer required. 

And to throw another spanner in the works QVW can theoretically be run multiple times per week not just the week.  It's not normal but can happen.

Comment: If you don't want previous weeks, you could easily delete the QVDs you no longer need using "execute cmd /r c:\path\to\qvd.qvd" and just keep the 2 you want. Again if they are named sensibly that should be pretty straightforward. I'm not sure what you mean by "run multiple times per week not just the week", sorry.

Comment: What I meant to type was when I said "run multiple times per week not just the week", is that the QVW can be run multiple times per week not just once per week.

Comment: Yeah, so if you overwrite that week's QVD, that won't duplicate the data when you load the QVDs back in...